# Unable to load culture-specific RESX using ResourceManager.GetResourceSet

Tags: c#, localization

I have the following RESX files declared in my .NET Framework MVC project:

[image]

The default culture is `de-CH`.

I have the following code for retrieving a `ResourceSet`:

```
public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

public ResourceSet ResourceSet
{
    get
    {
        var resMgr = new ResourceManager(nameOfResource, Assembly.Load(assemblyName));

        return resMgr.GetResourceSet(cultureInfo: Culture, createIfNotExists: false, tryParents: true);
    }
}
```

I have some code which, for a given set of `CultureInfo` objects tried to load the corresponding `ResourceSet` objects.

But for some reason it always loads only the `ResourceSet` for the default culture, `de-CH`. And if I set `tryParents` to `false` then it returns `null`.

What am I doing wrong? If I set...

```
Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
```

...and then call `ResourceSet` why doesn't it load the content from *Create.en-US.resx*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself: the second argument passed to `GetResourceSet` - `createIfNotExists` has a misleading name. The name implies that a resource object will be *created* if one doesn't already exist whereas the documentation explains it differently (my emphasis):

> true to **load** the resource set, if it has not been **loaded** yet; otherwise, false.

Once I set this value to `true` the expected culture-specific resource sets were loaded.